# Sequence of complex numbers and the series diverging or converging

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am currently very stuck on how to answer this question:

Let $(a_n)_n$ be a sequence of complex numbers, and suppose that there is a real number K such that $K<|a_n|$ for infinitely many $n$. Does the series $$\sum_{n\geq0}a_n$$ converge?

any help would be greatly appreciated as I am very confused.

Comment: I edited your latex. Please have a look at the changes I made. Each mathematical expression should always only have one opening dollar sign and one closing dollar sign. So, `($a_n$)$_n$` is *bad*, while `$(a_n)_n$` is *better*. There is no need to exclude the parentheses from the math.

Comment: $-1$ is a real value, so $K = -1$ would be a valid choice. Is there some further constraint to impose on $K$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

- If the series converges, then its partial sums are Cauchy.
- If $S_n$ is the $n$-th partial sum ($S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n a_n$), then look at the value $|S_n - S_{n-1}|$ for the case when $|a_n|>K$

Comment: Thank you for your response. So if we say that in general $|S_n - S_{m}|$ = |$\sum_{k=m+1}^n a_k| < K$ for all n>m>N then the series converges. However, we have that  |$\sum_{k=m+1}^n a_k| > K$ so therefore would the series diverge? I am very confused on this topic so I could be completely on the wrong track and wrong.

Comment: @mathsguy123 There is no $m$ in $|S_n - S_{n-1}|$. Your first equation makes no sense. The expression $S_n - S_{n-1}$ simplifies much more.

Comment: I have corrected it.

Comment: @mathsguy123 But yes, the general idea is that the series diverges. Because you can, for any $N$, find some $n$ such that $n>N$ and $|a_n|>K$. Then, if you set $m=n-1$, you get that $|S_n-S_m| >K$, meaning that the sequence is not Cauchy.

Comment: so my argument is valid? and I understand now. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @mathsguy123 Your argument is valid, but not very well expressed mathematically. You have the right idea, you just have to write it down correctly and rigorously enough, making it clear always which statement follows from what result.